# Magento 2 - how to skip the cache when getting system config value?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to get config values using:

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
    $config_path,
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
);
```

& it returns the cached value.
Is there any way to make it skip the cache **without** disabling it?
*I want the cache to be enabled but still bypass it for this value only.
**I also don't want to always clear the cache programmatically before getting it.
-- Any idea?

Comment: //Follow below link for solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180530/magento2-config-value-cached

Comment: As I said, clearing the cache before getting the data is not the solution I'm looking for. I need a way to get the current updated value without clearing or disabling the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you basically need is to query the database directly.

So Inject a `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\CollectionFactory` in your class.

Then you can query the database : 

`$collection = $collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addScopeFilter($scope, $scopeId, $section)`

The `$section` is the path, 
`$scopeId` the id of the store or website depending on the scope
& $scope is either "stores" or "website" or "default".

Comment: I don't know whether it is version depend but Magento 2.3.4 translates $section as "like $section/%'. So if you push  for example 'web/unsecure/base_url' as $section  then it will fail you must enter only 'web/unsecure', in that case you get collection of config values for 'web/unsecure'. If you want to fetch only one config value you must add filter like $collection->addFieldToFilter('path', ['eq' => 'web/unsecure/base_url']);